# Angular 2 data binding under the hood

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I read a lot about how Angular 2 handles databinding. But I can't find enough information how it works under the hood (how is a DOM change event detected and propagated, how is a data (object) property change detected).

What I would like to know is how Angular 2's change detection is implemented. Do they still use a dirty-check-polling mechanism or has it changed to a DOM-event-based mechanism (which should be faster)?

Comment: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html